# Почему setcookie устанавливает куки для определенного раздела сайта?

Tags: php, cookie

На сайте в точке входа есть вот такой код:

```
if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['qwerty']) && empty($_COOKIE['qwerty'])) {    
  setcookie('com_qwerty', $_GET['com_qwerty']);
  setcookie('com_source', $_GET['com_source']);
  setcookie('com_values', $_GET['com_values']);
  setcookie('com_info', $_GET['com_info']);
  setcookie('com_data', $_GET['com_data']);
}
```

После перехода на любую страницу в куки попадают нужные данные, при этом в колонке "Path" указывается путь до раздела сайта из URL по которому перешли. 
[image: скрин из вкладки application]

Всё бы хорошо, но на других страницах сайта эти сохранённые куки уже не видны. Они как будто затираются. Нужно чтобы эти куки были сохранены и доступны на всех страницах сайта пока пользователь не покинет сайт. Как быть?

Comment: как вы определяете что на других страницах они не видны ?

Comment: перехожу на них и смотрю вкладку "Application" в панели разработчика хром

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция setcookie() должна не только устанавливать имя и значение куки, но и срок действия, а также путь, где кука будет действовать: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Comment: А по умолчанию как раз - текущая директория.

Comment: А нужно для всего сайта.

Comment: А я разве спорю? Автор должен задать четвертый параметр как '/'

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку на док) в очередной раз ума хватило только чтобы написать этот кусок.. кода. а в документацию заглянуть не хватило